# Solve this algebraic equation

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

[image]

Wait what? Is there any equation?

Comment: I see $2x^2$, but don't know what to do with it. Also I don't know the puzzle `slitherlink`, so probably no chance for me...

Comment: @WhatsUp Slitherlink is one of the classic puzzle genres, and you can find tons of easy to hard puzzles on the Internet.

Comment: @Bubbler Thank you for the information. Yes, I understand that there are much information available. What I meant is that other people probably would solve it in much shorter time, given that I had to learn the rules and techniques from the very beginning...

Comment: @WhatsUp You can always practice the genre yourself, and then hopefully you'll have a chance when a new one appears. Also, if you're interested in [tag:grid-deduction] in general, take a look at many various genres, which will give you some insights and intuition so that you have a chance with a new *genre*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> First, there are LOTS of zeroes.
>  [image]

> I got up to this point with quick deductions before stopping to breathe:
>  [image]

> And, continuing on…
>  [image]

> Now, we notice that the right side of the 2 at Row 10 Column 13 cannot be part of the loop, or else it would have no way to extend further without violating both 2’s to its left and right. From this, more lines are being completed:
>  [image]

> And finally the two 1’s at the bottom right allow us to complete the loop:
>  [image]

> The loop looks like a 36. I’m not sure whether the exponent 2 applies to the x or the other 2, but I’m going to take a shot and assume that we want to solve $2x^2 = 36$ here.
>  $x^2 = 18$
>  $x = 3\sqrt2$

Comment: Whoa! That surprised me!

Comment: @00xxqhxx00 once i saw your puzzle (which was another great one) appear i just could not resist putting it to rest :P